# Почему рекомендуется создавать ArrayList следующим образом?

Tags: java, android

Рекомендуется писать вместо

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

следующую реализацию:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
```

Почему рекомендуется писать именно так? Какое  в этом различие?

Comment: Принято работать с интерфейсами, чтобы не ограничивать разработчика конкретной реализацией листа. Вот поэтому и объявляют переменную `list` типа `List` а реализация может быть какой угодно будь то `ArrayList` или `LinkedList`;  Хотя не знаю это всего лишь мои мысли!

Comment: Для локальных переменных единственное и при этом сомнительное преимущество - экономия времени на набор символов `List` вместо `ArrayList`. А для полей, параметров методов и возвращаемых методами значений - да, "program to an interface".